# How do I check the ranking of an engineering conference, and determine whether presenting there will be useful for my CV?

Tags: conference, ieee, ranking

I am a final year student of engineering. I have submitted a paper for presentation at IEEE Power and Energy Conference 2016 - Illinois USA to be held on 19th and 20th February 2016.

The paper has been accepted and I am excited about the same. I am in the planning stage of going and presenting the paper at conference. My departments HOD and most of my teachers are supportive and have encouraged me to attend the conference.

One of my seniors has however commented that I must check the ranking of conference before deciding to attend.

How do I check the conference ranking?? If I find that the conference is not ranked how does it affect the importance of presenting at IEEE conference and addition to my CV.

I am planning for a career in research and in the process have applied to some US universities for PhD. Will this addition to my CV be useful??

Awaiting a reply before proceeding to book tickets and apply for visa.

Comment: _One of my seniors has however commented that I must check the ranking of conference before deciding to attend._ — To be more specific, you must check that this is is a legitimate conference, and not a scam that allows people to exchange money for CV bullets. I don't know anything about this specific conference, but the mere fact that it's being held at my university—one block away from my office—makes me think it's legit.  Bring a coat; it can get *cold* here in February.

Comment: Side note: Usually it isn't the presentation that goes on your CV but the publication, and in most fields you are required to register and present for it to be published.

Comment: Does the ranking really matter that much?  Why do people obsess over minutiae?  As JeffE says, it's an IEEE conference, so it's not just junk.  And you'd be better going and presenting a paper than *not* going and *not* presenting a paper.

Answer (score 6):

It is a legitimate IEEE conference organised by the local IEEE section in Illinois and its proceedings will get indexed to IEEExplore. Also the University of Illinois is well-known for its Power Engineering - Power Electronics area so you will get to meet some people in the area.

On the other hand, it is not one of the major PES conferences for the year so do not expect many sessions or huge audiences in the conference. you might want to consider that especially if you plan to travel from abroad and need to pay flights - accomodation - registration. Last year's table of contents is available here so you can judge for yourself:http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7064877

(Probably you should have searched these before you submitted the paper and not after it has been accepted!)